# check if monitor cable is connected?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, hardware

I am working on a c# winForm application and want to detect as soon as monitor cable (HDMI, VGA etc) plugged in.
I could detect when monitor cable plugged in and plugged out using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858005/detecting-hdmi-cable-event-within-net) and use this code :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)        
    {

        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;

        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanging += SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanging;

        Console.Read();
    }

    static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display settings have been changed.");
    }

    static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanging(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Display settings are changing now...");
    }

}
}
```

But there is a problem. When application run and monitor cable connected or disconnected, the application detect and show message, but if monitor cable connected before start application, can`t to detect.
How can i detect if monitor cable plugged in In all scenarios?

Comment: @mjwills I want stop application if HDMI cable connected. but if HDMI connected before starting project, can`t to detect. is there any way to do it?

Comment: If all you want is to know whether an external monitor is connected, then you can look at the `Screens.Count` property.

Comment: @mjwills Oh, I did not care VGA cable!!!,I want to application stop if HDMI and VGA connected in all scenarios

Comment: @SamAxe Thanks, is there any sample to use it?

Comment: No.  If you don't know how to use object properties you should take a remedial C# course.

Comment: @SamAxe Thanks, i did it